# android firebase dynamic link is only working if app is installed earlier why?

Tags: android

I have implemented a firebase dynamic link in my app, and send the inviter data into it. when the user clicks on the link then it goes up to play store and invitee can install the app and open. but the inviter data is not going at this time. data is only going when the invitee again click on the dynamic link and goes to the app directly(without going on play store). why this happening don't know.
I want the inviter data should go at first click on the link and route after invitee install and open the app, no need to click dynamic Invite link again.please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit now after the answer has been accepted i should point to the correct solution as it's in comment
for this situation the solution was to set splash screen launch mode to singletask

```
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and try to access the dynamic link data in next activity if cannot read in splash

I have never used dynamic link but after bit of seach i found alot of people with same issue. and found some people who had workareound for it.
here is github issue link : https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1084
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1084#issuecomment-420974134
and can you try to set the activity launch mode to single task this could help according to 
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1084#issuecomment-539111101

I know this issue is related to react native but can you at least give it a chance.

Comment: ok thanks, let me use it and upload my app again on play store.

Comment: I added android:launchMode="singleTask" in both my splash and login page where I handle the intent. but it did nothing.

Comment: You should have set splash activity launch mode only

Comment: Ohh sorry, it's my fault, this is working. Thanks, Sir.